# Testflight : "You are currently not testing any apps" error

Tags: ios, testflight

I have submitted my apps to test flight and able to download it using testflightapp.com. However, when I access it through the testflight app itself, it says "You are currently not testing any app"?

I have checked the following link but it's not helpful
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829653-i-don-t-see-any-apps-after-connecting-my-device-to-my-account-

Comment: The _TestFlight_ app is the Apple's internal test-flight feature and platform – the _testflightapp.com_ is an independent 3rd party site. there is no connection between them.

Comment: @holex Apple bought 'testflightapp'. I'm assuming the website will eventaully be phased out in favour of the iTunes Connect integration.

Comment: @kmcgrady, yes, the Apple has bought it to shut it down. the concept of the two ideas are completely different – I highly doubt that there would be any integration or migration between those those sites. the common sense (=business interests) indicates that the _testflightapp.com_ will be functioning by iOS9 comes out in next october, and no further... they will use the name only in the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you donwloaded the Apple Testfligt App. It's different than the system you are using. You need to access the testflightapp-website with your Ipad/Iphone. Have a look in your emails. There should be a Testflight link. Open it with your iOS device and it should work. It will reate an icon on your home-screen which looks like an App but is just the link to testflightapp.com

Comment: So what is the Apple TestFlight App for ?

Comment: Apple bought Testflight and is now integrating it into their Appstore. Testflightapp.com is just the Testfliught how it was before Apple bought it. They stopped working on it and I'm surprised that it hasn;t been shut down yet.

Answer (score 1):

Other tip, always open your TestFlight emails with the mail default app from the iPad/iPhone or Safari.

I was using gmail app to open the mail but it was failing